# Centering images in a div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to the images in this gallery to auto center themselves and no matter what I do they refuse to go to the center. Yes I understand  should not be used anymore but it still should work. Please help
HTML

```
<div id='gallery_gallery'>
            <center>
                    <div id='imageList'>
                    <center>
                    <?php
                        $directory = 'images/gallery';
                        $files = scandir($directory);
                        $file_length = sizeof($files);
                        $to = 16;
                        $start = 2;
                        if($to > $file_length) $to = $file_length;
                        for($i=$start; $i <= $start-1+$to; $i++)
                        {
                            echo "<div class='galleryImage'><img src='images/gallery/".$files[$i]."' width='100%' onclick='showImage(\"".$files[$i]."\")'></div>";
                        }
                    ?>
                    </center>
                    </div>
                </center>
            </div>
```

CSS

```
#gallery_gallery
{
position: absolute;
top: 75px;
left: 80px;
width: 825px;
height: 960px;
}
#imageList
{
background-color: yellow;
width: 825px;
text-align: center;
}
.galleryImage
{
width: 180px;
height: 180px;
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
}
.galleryImage img
{
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
padding: 10px;
}
.galleryImage img:hover
{
cursor: pointer;
}
```

RESULT
http://sonny.hostingsiteforfree.com/gallery.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the CSS is not following standards.

The ImageWrapper `galleryImage` has `overflow:hidden` with the image `galleryImage img` has `padding:10px` which cause everything to go unstable here.

I have created a [`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/MarmeeK/KdLd6/) here you may check the changes...

CSS:

```
#gallery_gallery {
    position: absolute;
    top: 75px;
    left: 80px;
    width: 825px;
    height: 960px;
    text-align:center;
    background:#777;
}
#imageList {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 825px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left:10px;
}
.galleryImage {
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin:10px 10px;
}

.galleryImage img {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;

}
.galleryImage img:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Also, we need to close the img tag in PHP code. using this self closing of tag `/>`

This causes your image style not work properly.

```
 echo "<div class='galleryImage'><img src='images/gallery/".$files[$i]."' width='100%' onclick='showImage(\"".$files[$i]."\")' /></div>";
```

Check the fiddle its working fine.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add `text-align: center;` to `#imageList`. Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VLJYq/

Comment: No, that didn't work. For some reason the images brought by php will not center.

Answer (score 0):

Its all because of the float style you are using, if you  remove the div with class 'galleryImg', it will work properly.

```
echo "<img src='images/gallery/".$files[$i]."' width='180' onclick='showImage(\"".$files[$i]."\")'>";
```

try this one.

Answer (score 0):

Just add:

```
width: 731px;/* change from 825px */
display: inline-block;//new added
```

to `#imageList`

**Note:** I have tested this.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove your css
2. Remove "center" tag from #gallery_gallery that you have written.
3. Apply Below CSS.

   ```
    .pageWrap { margin: auto; width: 1000px;}

    #main_content_gallery {background: url("../images/gallery_bg.jpg") no-repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);height: 1722px;padding: 72px;}

    .main_content {clear: both;width: 100%;}

    #gallery_gallery {clear: both;margin: 0 61px;padding: 0;width: 100%;}

    #imageList {background-color: yellow;clear: both;float: none;text-align: center;width: 80%;}

    .galleryImage {float: left;height: 180px;overflow: hidden;width: 180px;}

    .galleryImage img {min-height: 100%;min-width: 100%;padding: 10px;}

    #imageList {text-align: center;}

    #mainmenu {left: 1px;position: relative;width: 800px;}

    #mainmenu, #mainmenu ul {list-style: none outside none;margin: 0;padding: 0;}

    .pageWrap {margin: auto; width: 1000px;}

    #mainmenu a {color: black;float: left;font-family: 'Coda',cursive;font-size: 20px;padding: 0 30px 12px;text-decoration: none;text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000;}

    #floatBox {background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);display: none;height: 100%;left: 0;position: fixed;top: 0;width: 100%;}

    #float_image { height: 600px;}

    #float_tools {margin: auto;opacity: 0.3;transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out 0s;width: 50px;}

    #floatimg {border: 10px solid white;border-radius: 5px;float: none;height: 550px;}
   ```

Let me know if it doesn't works.

Answer (score 0):

You should changes height and width of ".galleryImage" css class, like this:

```
.galleryImage {
    float: left;
    height: 243px;   /* changed from 180*/
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 205px;   /* changed from 180*/
}
```

I have tested this on your link, It works well.

Answer (score 0):

Try use the margin

```
margin:0 auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just rewrite this style

```
 .galleryImage {
width: 180px;
height: 180px;
display: inline-block;
overflow: hidden;
}
```